# Is there any equivalent for MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA after Android 10?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am developing an Android gallery app. I want to show the abusolute path of image to users, which looks like `/strorage/emulated/0/DICM/Camera/file.jpg`. However, `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated in API level 29. So is there any other equivalent ways to get absolute path after API 29?

Here's my current code:

```java
Uri tableUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, // Android Studio shows this constant is decrepcated
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(tableUri, projection, null, null, null);

// Then fetch data from cursor...
```

Comment: Just use it. If it works it works. And it is not that deprecated.

Comment: Google decided to reinstate it.